# Having trouble to complete Unittest class based views in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

How can I complete this views unittest with django? 
I am getting started with unittest and for some reason i am not able to complete the first class based views test successfully.

models.py

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'books'
    template_name = 'snippets/list.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import (BookListView)
from . import views


app_name = 'snippets'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='book_list'),
```

views.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from snippets.models import Book
import json



class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_book_list_GET(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('snippets:book_list'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'snippets/list.html')
```

Below is the feedback crashing from the terminal

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.061s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: You're passing a URL name, not an actual path, to the client.

Comment: any example? I am going through the entire internet and cant seem to find anything different than what i have used above. I have added "reverse" for the URL name, still not passing the test.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_book_list_GET(self):
        response = self.client.get('snippets:book_list')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'snippets/list.html')
```

you need to pass the url here, with `django.urls.utils.reverse` which would give you the relative url for the view

Comment: any example? I am going through the entire internet and cant seem to find anything different than what i have used above. I have added "reverse" for the URL name, still not passing the test.

Comment: Does your booklist url takes any arguments

Comment: no, the only thing not mentioned is ```paginate_by = 5``` used in BookListView(ListView). By the way, now the error is ```AssertionError: 302 != 200```

Comment: It is possible that django redirects `path` to `path/` resulting in 302